What is the legal status of the Avengers before Civil War and after Winter Soldier?
After the incident in Winter Soldier, S.H.I.E.L.D is no longer in charge of the group of Avengers. Before the incident of Sokovia Accords, the Avengers seems to be running independently from the government.
My question is, what is the (legal) status of the Avengers in these moments? They are not under the government but owning weapons clearly not for civilian usage (like the Quinjet).

It's arguable that the Avengers were ever under S.H.I.E.L.D.'s authority but rather were brought together by that organisation for whatever reason. It's unlikely they would have taken actual orders.
Regardless, it seems to me that there are two possible descriptions that fit the Avengers, pre-Sokovia Accords.

Militia


A militia is generally an army or some other fighting organization of non-professional or part-time soldiers (Wikipedia)


A private group of armed individuals that operates as a paramilitary force and is typically motivated by a political or religious ideology (Merriam Dictionary)


Vigilantes


A person who tries in an unofficial way to prevent crime, or to catch and punish someone who has committed a crime, especially because they do not think that official organizations, such as the police, are controlling crime effectively. Vigilantes usually join together to form groups. (Cambridge Disctionary)


A member of a self-appointed group of citizens who undertake law enforcement in their community without legal authority, typically because the legal agencies are thought to be inadequate. (Oxford Dictionary)

On the subject of weapons, I believe that is not really relevant to the overall question. It's quite legal (in some countries/states) to own weapons "not intended for civilian use", and in any case, Stark owns the weapons, Mjolnir aside, since he invented them, and the others rely on their own talents or powers.

Is there a super hero anywhere that couldn't be considered a vigilante?

Those who work for the government? US Agent, the MCU Thunderbolts potentially?
